# What's the meaning of the first arguments in FirstOrderHold in Pydrake?

Tags: drake

An example is

```
initial_x_trajectory = PiecewisePolynomial.FirstOrderHold(
    [0., 4.], [initial_state.get_value(),
               final_state.get_value()])
```

I'm wondering what's the meaning of this [0., 4.]. I checked the document: FirstOrderHold(breaks, samples), but still confused about the "breaks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`breaks` are the points in time that define each segment of the piecewise polynomials, and `samples` are the values of the piecewise polynomial at the `breaks`.  https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1trajectories_1_1_piecewise_polynomial.html

Comment: Understand! Thanks!